# Why does xcodebuild give different build results than XCode UI

Tags: xcode, build, xcodebuild, workspace

I have a series of projects within a workspace, and trying to use the following type of command to build them via the command line:

```
"Xcodebuild -project XXX"
or 
"Xcodebuild -workspace XXX -scheme YYY"
```

Some of my projects build fine but others give strange errors, like "'XXX' for instance message does not declare a method with selector" or "ld: library not found for -lMyLibrary"

However all these projects build fine from within the XCode UI without issues.

Based on this is seems that the command line and UI builds are using a different toolset, but that seems like a very bad idea so I'm hoping I'm wrong about this. Or possibly there are just a few different build flags being set on the command line build.

I can try to troubleshoot the issues one by one but I'm hoping I can write a script which does the exact same type of build as the UI.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? Having exactly the same "library not found" problem and can't for the life of my figure out what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Without including `-configuration`, xcodebuild is going to use the default configuration for each project. Generally that's Release. In Xcode, the Configuration you select will be applied to every project regardless of default.

Given your errors, your most likely problem is that you've used the build pane ([why I hate the build pane for large projects](http://robnapier.net/blog/build-system-1-build-panel-360)), and you've made the classic mistake of applying some settings for Debug rather than all configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I don't think that is the cause of my problem, since I just tried two builds with "-configuration Release" and "-configuration Debug" and both are failing in the same way.